# Drawing custom colored arc inside canvas

Tags: android, view, android-canvas, android-custom-view, android-circularview

I am in quite need of help.
Need to draw this gradient colored view inside canvas in customview.
But cant achieve it. angles and circular positioning is okay but colors are going crazy and showing wrong,spoiled colors. Can some experienced one guide me through this canvas drawing crazyness,please ?
this is what i want to achieve

[image: target view]

```
class CustomWheel : View {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context, null)
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet, 0)
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attributeSet,
        defStyleAttr
    )
    val section1Paint = Paint().apply {
        val gradient = LinearGradient(0f,0f,0f,20f,
            intArrayOf(resources.getColor(R.color.paint1start),resources.getColor(R.color.paint1end)),
            floatArrayOf(0f, 0.5f), Shader.TileMode.MIRROR)
         this.shader = gradient

    }
    val section2Paint = Paint().apply {
        val gradient = LinearGradient(0f,0f,0f,20f,
            intArrayOf(resources.getColor(R.color.paint2start),resources.getColor(R.color.paint2end)),
            floatArrayOf(0f, 1f), Shader.TileMode.MIRROR)
        this.shader = gradient

    }
    val section3Paint = Paint().apply {
        val gradient = LinearGradient(0f,0f,0f,20f,
            intArrayOf(resources.getColor(R.color.paint3start),resources.getColor(R.color.paint3end)),
            floatArrayOf(0f, 1f), Shader.TileMode.MIRROR)
        this.shader = gradient

    }
    val section4Paint = Paint().apply {
        val gradient = LinearGradient(0f,0f,0f,20f,
            intArrayOf(resources.getColor(R.color.paint4start),resources.getColor(R.color.paint4end)),
            floatArrayOf(0f, 1f), Shader.TileMode.MIRROR)
        this.shader = gradient

    }
    val section5Paint = Paint().apply {
        val gradient = LinearGradient(0f,0f,0f,20f,
            intArrayOf(resources.getColor(R.color.paint5start),resources.getColor(R.color.paint5end)),
            floatArrayOf(0f, 1f), Shader.TileMode.MIRROR)
        this.shader = gradient

    }


    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        val x = ((width - height / 2) / 2).toFloat()
        val y = (height / 4).toFloat()
        val oval = RectF(x, y, width - x, height - y)


        canvas?.drawArc(oval, 0F, 72F, false, section1Paint)
        canvas?.drawArc(oval, 72F, 144F, false, section2Paint)
        canvas?.drawArc(oval, 144F, 216F, false, section3Paint)
        canvas?.drawArc(oval, 216F, 288F, false, section4Paint)
        canvas?.drawArc(oval, 288F, 360F, false, section5Paint)


    }
}
```

[image: result]

this is what i get :)

Answer (score 0):

Try change all "false" to "true" in canvas.drawArc()